# How to tell Bundler to use gems installed systemwide (production deployment)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, capistrano, bundler

When deploying a Rails app with Capistrano, I want Bundler to install gems to `shared/bundles` dir ONLY IF it can't find gems installed systemwide already. How do I do it?

For example, if I have a `pg` gem `v 0.14` already installed on the system, I want Bundler to use it and not build and install a new one into `shared/bundles` dir of my application.

I'm using Ubuntu Server and RVM is installed for multiple users.

Answer (score 4):

Bundler allows using **shared**(rubygems) and **vendored**(bundler) gems, by default `bundler/capistrano` is configured with:

```
set :bundle_flags, "--deployment --quiet"
```

which forces vendored gems only,

you can switch back to shared gems with explicit:

```
set :bundle_flags, "--system --quiet"
```

to still install in `vendor` but use shared gems too:

```
set :bundle_flags, "--path #{shared_path}/bundles --quiet"
```

if the deployment was already ran with `--deployment`(the default) then it could help to run the deploy once with:

```
set :bundle_flags, "--no-deployment"
```

Comment: Just to make sure: I don't have `vendor/bundle` directory in `current/`. As far as I'm concerned, all gems are installed in `shared/bundles` which is outside of `current/`. Does this mean I should instead use `--path shared/bundles` in the last line of code you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a feature of Bundler, essentially it's dependency isolation – you don't want your app depending on an outside, system gems like this. Updating the system gem could then have a impact on running applications.

If you're already using capistrano you should be using `require "bundler/capistrano"` in your script which will install them in `shared/bundles` anyway. You could look into packaging before hand as well: http://gembundler.com/v1.2/bundle_package.html