# Why is 'gem list' not showing the available gem that 'bundle install' show?

Tags: rubygems, rvm, capistrano, passenger

On my production server :

When I do a bundle install I can see 'using schema_plus (1.0.1)' message
When I do a 'gem list' I don't see it anymore.

Why is there a difference between both ?
That should never happen ! Running a server with RVM seems to be a nightmare. Any advice is welcome.

I don't have any gemset but the 'default and the global on the server.
Current gemset is set to 'default'

During deployement Capistrano use following options :

```
set :bundle_flags, ""
set :bundle_dir, ""
require 'bundler/capistrano'
set :rvm_type, :system
require 'rvm/capistrano'
```

my enabled appache module : /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load is using following configuration :

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-3.0.19
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p392/ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14836718/497756 - extra options not mentioned there is `--system` - try:

```
set :bundle_flags, "--system"
```