# bundle cannot find the global shared gem in nginx/passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, rubygems, bundle, passenger

The passenger reports error that the gem json cannot be found. While other gems can be found because they are installed by `bundle install`. However, json was default installation by ruby 2.1.1.

And it is wired that bundle shows json has been deleted.

```
$ bundle show json
The gem json has been deleted. It was installed at:
/home/canoe/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.1
```

But gem can still find it on system.
$ gem list json
json (1.8.1)

And json is installed at this location /home/canoe/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/json.rb.

I don't use cap while deploying the rails4.1 application, so this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836119/how-to-tell-bundler-to-use-gems-installed-systemwide-production-deployment/14836718#14836718) doesn't work for me.

I don't want to package everything into somewhere, instead to use all current installed gems in the gemsets.

So, how to make bundle use system default gems in nginx passenger?

Comment: Passenger should have printed an error page with a dump of your environment variables. Can you double check whether all the important environment variables like GEM_PATH are correct?

Comment: Yes, I've set the GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME to the values which are shown by `bundle env`. So, that's why other non-system gems are visible to bundle in passenger.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same issue, but following post helped me: [fusion passenger issue with json gem when running on nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709281/fusion-passenger-issue-with-json-gem-when-running-on-nginx)

Maybe you are also using some ruby version control tool. As I'm using `RVM`.
According to the comment in above post. `passenger_ruby` need to be pointed to the RVM wrapper folder.

eg:

> passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p481/ruby;