# fusion passenger issue with json gem when running on nginx

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger

I have spent the better half of today trying to resolve an issue where fusion passenger fails to process the request due to some segment fault issue within the json gem.

There have been similar posts regarding this issue, however none of the solutions have appeared to work. I have tried to clear the gems and re bundle, e.g. gemset empty, bundle install.

The interesting this about this is running rails server is ok, and running fusion-passenger stand alone is fine too, only when running under nginx do I have this issue.

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

Web application could not be started
An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read this article for more information about this problem.
```

Raw process output:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and resolved it. ngnix was defaulting to ruby 1.9.3, a version fusion passenger has installed. I only installed one version 2.0.0 of ruby through rvm.  All i had to do was set the nginx config file to the ruby wrapper and all was good. The world is once again a happy place!

```
passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p481/ruby;
```